# Performing write and read operations with memory in verilog?

Tags: verilog

**Unable to read from memory**

Here I am performing first write operation to memory(storing in memory) then after performing read operation i have taken temp1 for storing read value from memory but I am getting "error" unable to read from memory

I want output from temp1 after performing read operation in memory

```
  module memory(clk,m_add,ead,ewr,mrd,temp1);

    input clk;
    input [7:0]m_add;
    input [7:0]ead;
    input ewr,mrd;

    output [7:0]temp1;

    reg [7:0] memr [0:255];
    reg [7:0]temp;

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
      if(ewr==1)
      begin
        memr[ead] <= 8'b00001111;
      end 
      else if(mrd==1) 
      begin
        temp <= memr[m_add];
      end
    end

    assign temp1=temp;

  endmodule

  module tb();

    reg clk,mrd,ewr;
    reg [7:0]m_add;
    reg [7:0]ead;

    wire [7:0]temp1;

    memory m1(clk,m_add,ead,ewr,mrd,temp1);

    initial begin
      clk=0;
      #5 ewr=1;
      #5 ead=8'b00000001;
      #10 mrd=1;
      m_add=8'b00000001;

      #40 $stop;
    end

    always #5 clk=~clk;

  endmodule
```

**I want output from temp1**

Comment: you can add this string to the tb module: `initial $monitor(temp1);`

Answer (score 1):

In your testbench, you never make `ewr` signal `0`. Therefore, you never pass the statement `if(ewr==1)` in your module. You can rewrite the initial block of your testbench as:

```
initial begin
    clk=0;
    #10 ewr=1; ead=8'b00000001;    // write operation
    #10 ewr=0;                     // bring ewr to 0
    #10 mrd=1; m_add=8'b00000001;  // read operation
    #10 mrd=0;                     // bring mrd to 0

    #40 $stop;
 end
```